# Can we install a `.zip` R package under linux?

Tags: r

I have found an old `R` package with a `.zip` extension on my PC. 
I would like to run it, but I do not have the `tar.gz` that was used to 
create it and I use linux. What are my options?

Comment: Also check the `DESCRIPTION` file, it should contain the platform under which it was built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this can be done this way:

- install `wine` (wine is not an emulator),
- install `R` for `Windows`, which you download manually from `CRAN`
- install the zip package using the usual commands (`install.packages("filename.zip",source=NULL)`). You will probably get error messages for the dependencies, but incrementally installing those, it should work.

Answer (score 3):

Few, essentially.

A `.zip` package for R is almost surely a *binary built for Windows* so you need to find a suitable Windows computer -- or emulator -- to use it.